# Regex(PHP): Avoid Capturing a certain word list

Tags: php, regex, pcre

If we take a text Like this

```
 <p>Portable <span class="shlt">Adobe</span> <span class="shlt">After</span>
 <span class="shlt">Effects</span> CC <span class="shlt">2018</span> 15.1.1.12 (x64)</p>
```

There are words between those `<span class="shlt"></span>` tags. I need to capture The title Only!

(You can clearly see that it contains *Portable Adobe After Effects CC 2018 15.1.1.12 (x64)*)

Is it possible to avoid capturing `<span class="shlt">` and `</span>` Parts?

And Capture only the **Portable Adobe After Effects CC 2018 15.1.1.12 (x64)** Text?

What I am currently trying to do is Capturing the words in between those tags. Is there a better way! A sample regex Code will be useful. In **PHP** Please...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/4265352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture groups inside of the regex by using (). Then you can parse out the array.
Here is an example.

```
$re = '/\<span class="shlt">([^<]*)<\/span>/m';
$str = 'Portable <span class="shlt">Adobe</span> <span 
class="shlt">After</span> <span class="shlt">Effects</span> CC <span 
class="shlt">2018</span> 15.1.1.12 (x64)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

this will remove the span tags

```
$str = 'Portable <span class="shlt">Adobe</span> <span 
class="shlt">After</span> <span class="shlt">Effects</span> CC <span 
class="shlt">2018</span> 15.1.1.12 (x64)';

preg_replace("/<\/?span[^>]*>/", "", $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Ok but what about those other words. The words which are not in span tags

Comment: \<span class="shlt">([^<]*)<\/span>([^<]*) this one will capture the words after too.

Comment: No buddy, It's not what i need. Those span tags are not always like that. they differ each time.So this may return wrong outputs sometimes.Also It does not return similar outputs all the time. I need to capture everything else except those span tags

Comment: you can make it as complex as it needs to be. I don't have all the cases to write the perfect regex, but this will get you there.

Comment: maybe you can use regex to remove the span tags?

Comment: preg_replace("/<\/?span[^>]*>/", "", $str); will remove the span tags.

Comment: Thanks man It will work. I totally forgot bout that function. Awesome. Thanks Dude!!!

Comment: Welcome, can you select my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Cause YES! Post It as a answer.I'll Select It. Thanks Dude.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a regex, you might use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and use [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to find your `<p>` element.

Then take the first match from the result and get the [textContent](http://at.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName("p")[0]->textContent;
```

That will give you:

```
Portable Adobe After Effects CC 2018 15.1.1.12 (x64)
```

Comment: Doesn't it also give those span tags.Also I do not have the Document File I need. I am just using cURL to get it...

Comment: According to the [docs](http://at.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent), this returns `The text content of this node and its descendants.`

Comment: But How do i use it if i was using cURL??

Comment: Then you load the html from the curl request into DOMDocument. When the response is a more complicated structure, you could then use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and create an xpath expression with [query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php).